# Cygwin and makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile, cygwin

I'm new to makefiles, and I'm using Cygwin to make my files. I have source files in three different directories and I compiled them using the [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/VPATH-and-Make.html) technique, but the object files are generated in the current directory.

I want all the object files to be generated in one directory 
and the target file in other directory. [That is, the .mk file in some other directory] How can I do that? How can I tell the compiler to generate them in the specified directory?

Here is my program:

```
vpath %.c bad good ugly
    gcc $(CFLAGS)   -c  $<  -o  $@
gola:goka.o foka.o hoka.o
    gcc $^  -o  $@
goka.o:goka.c
    gcc -c  $<
foka.o:foka.c
    gcc -c  $<
hoka.o:hoka.c
    gcc -c  $<
```

How do I put all object files in one directory and the `gola` [mk] file in the specified directory?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said where you want these files (and I couldn't make sense out of what you said about "mk file"), but this will put the object files in `obj/` and construct `gola` in `bin/`.

```
vpath %.c bad good ugly
#    gcc $(CFLAGS)   -c  $<  -o  $@ this line makes no sense                    

OBJECTS = obj/goka.o obj/foka.o obj/hoka.o

bin/gola: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $^  -o  $@

$(OBJECTS): obj/%.o : %.c
    gcc -c  $< -o $@
```

There are ways to make the makefile cleaner, shorter, more flexible, but they are advanced techniques.